# SqlDataAdapter error in c sharp

Tags: c#, c, vb.net

Hello I have an error with the data adapter in c sharp . How to fix?

```
 SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from View_1 where Words_Sh LIKE ' + @txbSearch + '%'", con);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@txbSearch", this.txbSearch.Text);
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd, con)
```

;

Comment: Your questions are really hard to read and understand.
For example, what error did you get?
How does `vb.net` and `c` relates to this question?

Comment: When you asked a similar question earlier, I pointed out that it would really help if you gave the exact error message. This remains the case. Saying "I have an error" ***doesn't help***.

Answer (score 3):

Don't add a single quote and the plus sign before the parameter placeholder

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from View_1 " + 
                                "where Words_Sh LIKE @txbSearch + '%'", con);
```

Also, I prefer to concatenate the wildcard symbol directly inside the parameter value.
Not sure if it makes any difference, though, just a matter of preferences and less clutter in the query string.

```
 SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from View_1 " + 
                                 "where Words_Sh LIKE @txbSearch", con);
 cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@txbSearch", this.txbSearch.Text + "%");
```

Answer (score 0):

EXAMPLE:

string commandText = "select * from View_1 " + "where Words_Sh LIKE @parameters"
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@parameters", "Parameter 1");

Answer (score 0):

Because of starting double quote, you should finish with double quotes before plus sign, but you can use single quote before double quote for LIKE operation.

```
 SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from View_1 where Words_Sh LIKE '@txbSearch%'", con);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@txbSearch", this.txbSearch.Text);
SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd, con);
```